# unable to validate data in Framework 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net

Recently I upgraded a project from Framework 4.6 to 4.6.1. We started facing the following issue:

We combine all the css files to generate a common css file. During this process AjaxControlToolkit Calendar creates a WebResource.axd file. When we try to process this file then the decryption fails and Error is thrown stating : "unable to validate data".

Following code is used:

```
var queryString = WebResourcePath.Split(new[] { '?' })[1];

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        var context = new HttpContext(new SimpleWorkerRequest("/WebResource.axd", queryString, textWriter));

        var urlEncodedData = context.Request.QueryString["d"];

        var encryptedData = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(urlEncodedData);

        var machineKeySection = typeof(MachineKeySection);
        var paramTypes = new Type[] { typeof(bool), typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]), typeof(int), typeof(int) };
        var encryptOrDecryptData = machineKeySection.GetMethod("EncryptOrDecryptData", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, paramTypes, null);

        try
        {
            var decryptedData = (byte[])encryptOrDecryptData.Invoke(null, new object[] { false, encryptedData, null, 0, encryptedData.Length });
            var decryptedContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData).Substring(1);
            var resourceParts = decryptedContent.Split('|');

            Assembly = AssemblyCache.Load(resourceParts[0]);
            ResourceName = resourceParts[1];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Error is thrown on the line : var decryptedData = (byte[])encryptOrDecry........

Some solution I went through suggested use of static machine key but we are already doing it.

NOTE : This is occuring only when we set httpRuntime targetFramework to 4.6.1 otherwise it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From forums.asp.net:

> So our problem was that some Webresource.axd requests are cached by
>   browsers (we didn't knew that...) but our machinekeys changes.
>
> Fix the machineKeys in Web.config and wait for all our users to clean
>   their browser cache.

**Comment:**
https://forums.asp.net/post/5620791.aspx

**Full thread:**
https://forums.asp.net/t/1963234.aspx?Unable+to+validate+data+EncryptOrDecryptData+problem

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Santiago, I have already gone through this solution. It did not help